# Writing Test Class for my search lightning component

Tags: unit-test, lightning-aura-components, search

I have been attempting to write a test class for my search function but its throwing me a little, my first time designing a lightning component so if someone could walk me through it that would I would hugely appreciate it.

**ContactList.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="ContactListController">

<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="account[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler event="c:SearchKeyChange" action="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>

<ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
        <li>
            <a href="{! '#/sObject/' + account.Id + '/view'}">
                <p>{!account.Name}</p>
                <p>{!account.Phone}</p>
                <p>{!account.BillingStreet}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
</aura:component>
```

**ControllerListController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },


    searchKeyChange: function(component, event) {
    var searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");
    var action = component.get("c.findByLocation");
    action.setParams({
      "searchKey": searchKey
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

})
```

**ContactListController.apxc**

```
public with sharing class ContactListController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findAll() {
        return [SELECT id, name, BillingStreet, phone FROM Account LIMIT 50];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findByLocation(String searchKey) {
        String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        return [SELECT id, name, phone, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE BillingStreet LIKE :name LIMIT 50];
    }



}
```

**SearchBar.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Search" onkeyup="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**SearchBarController.js**

```
({
    searchKeyChange : function(component, event, helper) {

    var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SearchKeyChange");
    myEvent.setParams({"searchKey":event.target.value});
    myEvent.fire();

}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro) on testing the apex controllers .

Currently you can natively test apex class but to test lightning component you will need write selinium or other front end testing like Jasmin .

Here is a [session from dreamforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh-FtOIsejA) that sheds some light into how to test lightning components